# vbscript .run show output

Tags: vbscript, wsh, remote-process

I can run successfully test.vbs with syntax:

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sEXE = """\\uncpath\file.exe"""
with CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  .Run sEXE & " ", 1, true ' Wait for finish or False to not wait
end with
```

however I want to store the output to `\\\uncpath\%computername%.txt`

This doesn't work:

```
sEXE = """\\uncpath\file.exe>>\\uncpath\%computername%.txt"""
with CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  .Run sEXE & " ", 1, true ' Wait for finish or False to not wait
end with
```

> error with line: with CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

This doesn't work either.

```
sEXE = """\\uncpath\file.exe"""
with CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  .Run sEXE & " >>\\uncpath\%computername%.txt", 1, true ' Wait for finish or False to not wait
end with
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.Run()` method doesn't have the ability to read the standard output from a task you use `.Exec()` for that, but you need a few changes to simulate the blocking that `.Run()` does for you automatically.

```
Dim WshShell, sEXE, cmd, result
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sEXE = """\\uncpath\file.exe"""
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set cmd = .Exec(sEXE)
  'Block until complete.
  Do While cmd.Status <> 1
     WScript.Sleep 100
  Loop
  'Get output
  result = cmd.StdOut.Readall()
  'Check the output
  WScript.Echo result
  Set cmd = Nothing
End With
```

---

The other approach is to prefix the `sEXE` variable so you are using `cmd /c` *(as the `>>` command is part of that)*.

This should work

```
sEXE = "cmd /c ""\\uncpath\file.exe >> \\uncpath\%computername%.txt"""
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  .Run sEXE & " ", 1, true ' Wait for finish or False to not wait
End With
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [WshScriptExec Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f38xsxe(v=vs.84).aspx) *(Returned by `.Exec()`)*
- [TextStream Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/312a5kbt(v=vs.84).aspx) *(Returned by `.StdIn`, `StdOut` and `StdErr`)*